# TypeScript Property 'selected' does not exist on type '{ id: string; value: string; label: string; color: string; }'.ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, native

I am using TypeScript with react native and when I write my code I got an error which is
Property 'selected' does not exist on type '{ id: string; value: string; label: string; color: string; }'.ts(2339) and Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ id: string; value: string; label: string; color: string; } | undefined'.ts(2322)

my code is:

```
export default class Instant extends Component {

  state = {
    one: [

      {
        id: "a0",
        value: "a0",
        label: 'A0',
        color: 'grey',
        checked: false,
      },
      {
        id: "a1",
        value: "a1",
        label: 'A1',
        color: 'grey',
        checked: false,
      },
      {
        id: "a2",
        value: "a2",
        label: 'A2',
        color: 'grey',
        checked: false,
      },
      {
        id: "a3",
        value: "a3",
        label: 'A3',
        color: 'grey',
        checked: false,
      },
      {
        id: "a4",
        value: "a4",
        label: 'A4',
        color: 'grey',
        checked: false,
      },
      {
        id: "a5",
        value: "a5",
        label: 'A5',
        color: 'grey',
        checked: false,
      },
    ],
    data: [
      {
        id: "Normal",
        value: "normal",
        label: 'normal',
        color: 'grey',
      },
      {
        id: "Gloss",
        value: "gloss",
        label: 'gloss',
        color: 'grey',
      },
      {
        id: "Strong",
        value: "strong",
        label: 'strong',
        color: 'grey',
      },
      {
        id: "Re-used",
        value: "reused",
        label: 're-used',
        color: 'grey',
      },
    ],
    two: [
      {
        id: "Color",
        value: "color",
        label: 'color',
        color: 'grey',
      },
      {
        id: "Black&White",
        value: "black&white",
        label: 'black and white',
        color: 'grey',
      },
    ],
    three: [
      {
        id: "Two-side",
        value: "twoside",
        label: 'two side',
        color: 'grey',
      },
      {
        id: "One-side",
        value: "oneside",
        label: 'one side',
        color: 'grey',
      },
    ],
  };

  onPress = (data: any) => this.setState({ data });
  render() {
    let selectedButton = this.state.data.find(s => s.selected == true);
    selectedButton = selectedButton ? selectedButton.value : this.state.data[0].label;
```

The final result must be like that, it works fine but it still have an error on VSCode.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtBA1.png)

Comment: The objects in your `this.state.data` do indeed not have a `selected` property. Are they supposed to? Is it optional?

Comment: If you're only going to allow selecting one of them, you might consider having a `selected` state member that you assign the object to, rather than making it a property of the object.

Comment: it is a code for instant calculation of customer pre-order, this depends on what the customer choose so it a single choice in each option group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not define `selected` property for your object.
Define an **optional** property in your object model.
For example:

```
export interface stateModel {
  id: string;
  value: string;
  label: string;
  color: string;
  checked: boolean;
  selected?: boolean;
}
```

Or if you can't define a model for your data, you can use type `any` for `state`:

```
 state : any = {...}
```

**ATTENTION:**

> *****The any type allows you to assign literally “**any**” particular value to that variable*****

Comment: I use the second way and then an error appear: in the "e" parameter let selectedButton = this.state.data.find(e => e.selected == true); which is "Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type."

Comment: Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type

Comment: this means you are using `--noImplicitAny`.
Try this:
`this.state.data.find(s: any => s.selected == true)`

Comment: Or add `"noImplicitAny": false` to `"compilerOptions"` object in **tsconfig.json**